# Orchard 1.10.x very slow in admin mode, Am I the only?

Tags: asp.net, orchardcms

Just accessing the Orchard Dashboard takes 2 minutes, site is an Azure Web App, SQL is Azure SQL, many modules, more than 150 tables and data not very big (nearly 5500 contentItems following the max id in ContentItemRecord )
The code is a custom version based on last 1.10.3.

Why clicking any Menu in the Admin takes more than 2 minutes, the received HTML being interpreted in some milliseconds when received from server.
Not speaking of accessing the MediaLibrary.

For front-end the cache is working but the Admin side is each day more a pain.
Being busy on other subjects I had not take care to this bad response time problem, and I was expecting Orchard Core would solve it.

But as I understand that Orchard Core will not be in position to replace all we already do with Orchard 1.10.x before a long time and work, I have to improve actual solution to be acceptable one more year...

I started profiling in VS2017 but was unable to find anything, the request from the dispatch async event taking all the 2 minutes delay to do its job ??? 
No evidence of duplicate requests.
Suspecting a razor compilation for each request...

Am I the only ?

CS

Comment: This is not normal. It superficially looks like an issue in the way the application connects to the database, like being in a different Azure data center, but it's hard to tell with so little actual information. It will be interesting to have some deeper insights from that profile, but one simple thing to check first could be to take any of those requests and look at its timing. Did you try using mini-profiler or a similar tool that gives you insights on SQL activity?

Comment: That was my intention, I will also check the azure side because there has been a lot of moves after our bizspark period ended and I was not always here...
Thanks for advice.

Comment: So miniprofiler told me that rendering the Menu shape is taking very long time ?
Dashboard access from homepage 
whole page 49 s sql 13s
ShapesDisplay Menu 34s sql 3s

Access to Taxonomies 
whole page 49 s sql 13s
ShapesDisplay Menu 34s sql 3s

Seems like a pb in menu display ?

Comment: Ok, I cached menus and everything is Ok now.

Comment: Interesting. What did you put in those menus that's taking so long? Any extensions that could explain why it even looks at taxonomies?

Answer (score 0):

Buildings Menus Shapes is very long, if there are many Admin menus, it can take several minutes, solution is to cache the 3 build menus or imagesets methods results in NavigationManager (by user).